# From grid bootstrap to carousel

Tags: css, carousel, bootstrap-5

Is that possible to have a carousel in mobile and a grid with cols in desktop?
I have a grid layout like this :

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
      <div class="col-8 ps-2">
        <h1>My title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
                    <div class="col-8 ps-2">
                        <h1>My title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
                    <div class="col-8 ps-2">
                        <h1>My title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
                    <div class="col-8 ps-2">
                        <h1>My title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
                    <div class="col-8 ps-2">
                        <h1>My title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
                    <div class="col-8 ps-2">
                        <h1>My title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
                    <div class="col-8 ps-2">
                        <h1>My title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
                    <div class="col-8 ps-2">
                        <h1>My title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-start">
                    <div class="col-8 ps-2">
                        <h1>My title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                        <span>Go more</span
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>


        </div>
```

So I have three columns with images and small text and I would like to have a carousel when I am on a small screen. I try to find a solution on the internet but the only solution I found was to speak about the owl carousel but I want to use the bootstrap carousel with only one image by one image.

What is the best to do that?

Comment: Do you mind including the Bootstrap 5 CDN in your head?

Comment: Yes, thanks I have the CDN in head. That s not the problem. I would like to write a code where I have this grid in desktop and a carousel in small screens...